# PHP download files from different hard drive using FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I am working a website, which let users download large files. problem with this is website owner says that when multiple user download files at a time, hard drive slows down and affect server performance.

He says to edit website so that website can download from different hard drives, at a time, for example football match from hard drive 1, and cricket match from hard drive 2. which divides loads between hard drives. I am not sure how to implement it, I have searched about it on many websites, but can't decide what to do, can anyone please suggest me how to implement it using FTP

also current website does not work on FTP

Comment: move host to something that scales

Comment: Your application code shouldn't know or care about things like storage hardware. That kind of stuff should happen at a much lower layer.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that FTP would help in that situation?

Comment: Are you running on Linux (or another opsys with soft-links so that sub-directories can be different filesystems located on different physical drives)?  What kind of URLs do you have for these big files?  Is there a pattern such that some web-server RewriteRule rules could direct the request to different sub-directories on different physical drives?  You solution here may not really be PHP-centred.

Answer (score 1):

It's the era of Cloud Computing.  Don't serve your big files directly from your own server.  Upload your big files once to a Cloud-based server and let users get them from that server.  Let the Cloud-provider worry about disk and network bandwidth.  Much more reliable and, these days, really inexpensive.

Most popular specific providers for doing this is "[Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)" and "[Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)".

Comment: actually this is server for local internet provider, which works on localhost only, we have a physical server, by connecting users and server through local area, users can download files at rate of 10 MB/s, I guess uploading files on cloud will not allow users to download at such a fast speed

Comment: Depends on your network speed.  Looks like you are using old 10Mb/s network cards in your LAN.  From my home, my internet connection is 266Mb/s (see http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/5851078067) so, at least for me, I could download from the Cloud much faster (especially since the Cloud servers from Amazon and Google are likely better connected to the Internet backbone than your servers).  But anyway looks like you might have a special situation where Cloud might not be best.

Comment: alright, I should go for some other options I guess, because in my area, average internet speed is 4 mb, while I use 2 mb :) anyway, thanks for your time

Comment: Can you upgrade the network card on the server with the physical disks from 10Mb/s to Gigabit ethernet (1000Mb/s)?  It might not be (just) your disk drives that are the bottleneck.  Gigabit cards can be had for as little as $10 although you do get what you pay for.